# Jaxb mapping anytype

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

I am trying to build a soap web service in java. One of my methods input parameter in soap should be

```
<s:element name="GetDocumentInfo">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="pPassword" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="xmlDoc">
<s:complexType mixed="true">
<s:sequence>
<s:any/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

In my java class I am mapping it to java variables

```
@XmlElement(name = "password")
private java.lang.String password;
@XmlElement(name = "doc")
private java.util.List<java.lang.Object> doc;
```

which is producing the wsdl output

```
<xs:complexType name="GetDocumentInfo">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="password" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="doc" type="xs:anyType"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

If I use Object I get JAXB marshalling error. what should be the doc variable type?

The soap client is a generic program (.net) and when they import the wsdl they get following error:

Object of type 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' cannot be converted to type 'System.Object[]'

I am not much familiar with jaxb.

Should I create a class with Xml and a variable of XmlDocument? what should be the XmlDocument variable type?

Comment: I have figured it out. I just needed to create a generic doc class with a list parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the details of the class which needs to be included.

```
public class doc<T> {

@XmlMixed
@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
protected List<T> content;

public List<T> getContent() {
    if (content == null) {
        content = new ArrayList<T>();
    }
    return this.content;
}

public void setContent() {
    content = this.content;
}
```

}